# Why is there weird data in strings I send over the internet using socket.h in C++?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

Note: Please be patient with me if I seem ignorant, I'm new to network programming in `C++`.

Whenever I send data through a connection in `C++` using `socket.h` (also happens using `winsock` when I'm on Windows), I get random data on the end of whatever I've sent.

For example, if I try to have the client send `"Hello"` to the server and then have the server print out whatever it's received, it'll come out as `"Hello�%"` or something similar.  Is this because I'm sending it over the internet, or does it have to do with the way I'm printing it (lacking a null terminator maybe).

It would be a problem if it was picking up random data as it was sent because I might write something that would download files or something like that, which it would obviously interfere with.  I'm fairly sure it's missing a null terminator or something, but attempting to add a '\0' to the end didn't do anything.  Also note that the data is being stored in C-Style strings.

Here's the code that sends the data:

```
send(sock, (char*)"Hello", strlen("Hello"), 0);
```

Here's the receiving code:

```
char recvbuf[100];
int len = strlen(recvbuf);
recv(sock, recvbuf, len, 0);
cout << recvbuf << endl;
```

Comment: The problem is likely that you're failing to send and/or read a nul terminator.  We can't say for sure unless you post code that demonstrates the problem though.

Comment: post code that shows how you send/recv messages and your char arrays.

Comment: I -1 this as it contains no code to reproduce, which means we can only speculate.

Comment: Print each character of the string as hexadecimal or decimal values.  This should give you a better idea of the strange characters.

Comment: @simonc - I added the code I'm using.

Answer (score 2):

```
send(sock, (char*)"Hello", strlen("Hello"), 0);
```

sends `strlen("Hello")` bytes, i.e. 5 bytes, without a nul terminator.

```
char recvbuf[100];
int len = strlen(recvbuf);
recv(sock, recvbuf, len, 0);
```

invokes undefined behaviour by reading through an uninitialised array looking for a terminator.  You may read beyond the end of your allocated memory doing this.  You almost certainly won't correctly assign `len` to 100.

As a very quick fix you could change your code to

```
const char* str = "Hello";
send(sock, str, strlen(str)+1, 0);
```

```
char recvbuf[100];
int len = recv(sock, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf), 0);
```

Note that this still won't be safe however.  There is no guarantee how many bytes `recv` will read in a single call.  To make your code robust, you'd need to either define a simple protocol that (say) uses the first 2 bytes of a message to specify the number of bytes that follow or change your client to read repeatedly, appending to `recvbuf` until it finds the null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen("Hello")` is `5`.  You're sending 5 bytes when you want to send 6.

Change your code to account for a terminating byte.

```
send(sock, (char*)"Hello", strlen("Hello") + 1, 0);
```